# I have ActivePerl64 5.16.1 installed alongside IIS7

Tags: iis-7, activeperl, otrs

I have ActivePerl64 5.16.1 installed alongside IIS7 on SBS2008

When i browse the site i get a 403 permission error.

I have checked all the permissions on the site root folder and all the logon credentials.

if i turn all directory browsing on, i can browse the folder, one level up.

the site is an instance of OTRS.

any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure `IIS_IUSRS` has 'owner' permissions on the OTRS folder, this way you actually have permissions to see the contents in the OTRS folder, and it allows you to install packages as well.